# using instanceof operator in Java

Tags: java, class, runtime, instanceof

I have a base class called `class Base` and two children classes

```
class A extends Base
```

and

```
class B extends Base
```

I have a method `foo` in `Base`.

Rather than putting the implementation of `foo` in `class A` and `class B`, so that I can do

```
void foo (Object o)
{
    // A's implementation
    assert o instanceof A;     
}


 void foo (Object o)
 {
     // B's implementation
     assert o instanceof B; 
 }
```

Is there anyway to put `foo` in Base, and still still be able to check for the runtime class? I've thought of something like this:

```
 void foo (Object o)
 {
    // Check that o is instanceof a runtime class
    assert o instanceof this.getClass(); // ????
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do something like that ?

Comment: yes, it's possible with the getClass().isInstance(obj) method, but why would you like to do this? If the foo overload is specific for each subclass, then you should do implement that in the subclass. Making a superclass aware of it's subclasses is bad. If the superclass needs to do something that only the subclass will know, consider using an abstract method declaration instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement your method like this:

```
public void foo() {
    if (this instanceof A) {
        // implementation for A
    }
    else if (this instanceof B) {
        // implementation for B
    }
}
```

But the point of polymorphism is to put the A implementation in A, so that this implementation can use A's private fields to implement the method (same for B, or course).

Answer (score 2):

```
getClass().isInstance(o)
```

That said, perhaps you want to constrain the type in a way the compiler can check? Generics can do that:

```
class Base<T extends Base<B>> {
    void foo(T o) { ... }
}

class A extends Base<A> {
    @Override void foo(A o) { ... }
}
```

Then,

```
new B().foo(new A());
```

will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

There is class method isAssignableFrom()

```
   getClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())
```

Comment: Erm, shouldn't it be the other way around? As in `getClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())`?

Comment: should it not be the reverse?

Comment: Yes, it is my mistake. Updated

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` will not work since the parameter can not be 'dynamic'.

You could use the `isInstance` method of `Class`

```
void foo (Object o)
{
    // Check that o is instanceof a runtime class
    assert getClass().isInstance(o);
}
```

but this has at least one possible problem:
it will result in an AssertionException if `this` is an instance of a subclass of `A` and the object is just a direct instance of `A`!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can check the class of an object using the instanceof operator:
object instanceof M

When you have a Class object, it would make sense to write:
object.getClass().isAssignableTo(MyClass.class)

http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/java/isassignablefrom/